# Why would you want to use the state_saving_rnn() function in TensorFlow?

Tags: out-of-memory, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

TensorFlow provides the following functions to create an RNN: `rnn()`, `dynamic_rnn()`, `state_saving_rnn()` and `bidirectional_rnn()`. I am wondering when you would want to use the `state_saving_rnn()` function?

I am guessing that this is for large RNNs. When unrolling through time, you effectively get a potentially very deep network, and if each layer has many parameters, the GPU may run out of memory. So the function would save the state at each timestep (perhaps to disk or perhaps to the CPU's memory rather than the GPU's?). Is that the general idea?

Could you please provide some code snippet, or a pointer to some code that uses it? In particular, I'd like to understand when exactly the state saver is called (at each time step?).

Answer (score 1):

There's some documentation on its use with examples here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.training.html

Look for the tf.contrib.training.SequenceQueueingStateSaver section in particular.

Comment: Thanks Pete. I'm sorry I missed this, sometime's it's hard to find what you're looking for in TF's documentation. It's actually easier to use Google Search: I just googled "site:tensorflow.org state_saving_rnn" and your link was #5. Now I'll know. ;-)